# Identify HW aquastat and add common wire to Honeywell aquastat

Tags: heating, furnace, thermostat-c-wire

[image][image]

This has been asked before, but I can't find any info on my Honeywell aquastat. The model number, normally on the inside paper on inside of cover, is missing so I do not have any model number.  There is no obvious identifying markings anywhere on the unit.  Nor can I find any info on the hi/lo limit switch. I believe it's a HW dual aquastat. It has numbers "l8054A" on front.  I'll post a picture of the unit.  I've taken it apart and made a schematic.  On the drawing is it possible to get "C" (common) by attaching wire to terminal labeled "111993" (this looks to be the common side of the secondary).  Any help identifying this HW aquastat or advice/comment on my plan to get "C" up to my new Nest thermstat would be appreciated.

Comment: Where do the two wires connected to the terminals at the top right of the aquastat head to?

Comment: "T" and "TV"?  They are to the thermostat. "TV" goes to the red wire on the old  thermostat and "T" goes to white on old thermostat.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: main question: can a "C" wire for a Nest thermostat be obtained by attaching a wire to terminal marked "111993" of hi/lo limit switch which is one wire of the transformer secondary (photo/schematic in photo above show this).  The other question, or request, is to identify  the Honeywell aquastat.  I can't seem to find any details on this unit.